# Understanding stack and base pointers in recursive function calls

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, callstack, att

We are on a x86-64 machine. Consider

```
int foo(int a) {
    if( a > 0)
            foo(a-1);

        return 0;
}
```

in assembly thats:

```
foo:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)
        jle     .L2
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        subl    $1, %eax
        movl    %eax, %edi
        call    foo
.L2:
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

Now I'm trying to figure out what exactly is going on here. I do get general assembly, question relates to line 2,3 and 4 of the assembly code fragment.

We run our program. We get virtual memory. Then the following happens when the function `foo()` is called the first time:

`pushq %rbp` We push 8-Bytes on to the stack whereas the stack starts at %rbp.

`movq %rsp, %rbp` We let %rsp point to %rbp i.e. to the start of the stack. That's why we pushed those 8-Bytes first - we needed storage for $rsp. Right?

`subq $16, %rsp` We move %rsp down 16 bytes.

Now I don't think I got that right. What exactly i the difference between `pushq` and just moving around `%rsp` directly?

When then basically do the if condition and the recursion. The recursion leads to the repetition of the above three lines. Now, doesn't that lead to successively moving the base and stack pointer by 16 bytes? How do we know where we once started?

Comment: The difference is that `push` writes something into the memory while moving `rsp` around doesn't. Also you can move `rsp` by any amount but you can only `push` fixed sizes (usually just 64 bits in 64 bit mode). You can also add to `rsp` to free things while `push` can't do that obviously.

Comment: As for the last question, look up what `leave` does. It's basically `mov %rbp, %rsp; pop %rbp`, it undoes the function prologue so it restores both `rbp` and `rsp` to their values at entry. PS: Yes, `sub` moves `rsp` by 16, yes, but you also have a `push` which moves it by `8` and a `call` which pushes the return address for another `8` bytes.